# custom handle post error - duplicate entry

Tags: tastypie

Is it possible to handle a duplicate entry error in a post request so that I can return details of the existing entry rather then an error message?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is. You'll have to override the `obj_create()` definition. Here's an example

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    bundle = self.full_hydrate(bundle)
    attempt = Attempt.objects.filter(**kwargs)
    if attempt.count() < 1:
        bundle.obj = Attempt(*kwargs)
    else:
        logger.info("Updating attempt")
        bundle.obj = attempt[0]
    return bundle
```